# Get past weeks days date of current month

Tags: android, android-layout, calendar, android-calendar

I try this but not get the format what i requires.

```
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE dd-MMM-yyyy");
    for (int i = 7; i >=1; i--) {
        Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, i);
        String day = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
        Log.i("days", day);
```

> Wednesday 06-Dec-2017
>   Tuesday 05-Dec-2017
>   Monday 04-Dec-2017
>   Sunday 03-Dec-2017
>   Saturday 02-Dec-2017
>   Friday 01-Dec-2017
>   Thursday 30-Nov-2017

I want format like this, Start date of week and End date of week..

> Oct 1-7 Oct 8-14 Oct 15-21

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code,

```
 public static void getWeeksOfMonth(int month, int year)
    {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE dd-MMM-yyyy");
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);

        int ndays = cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
       System.out.println(ndays+"<<<ff" );

        for (int i = 1; i <= ndays; i++)
        {
            String day = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
            System.out.println(day+"<<<" );
              Log.e("", day+"<<<");
            if(i % 7 == 0){
                Log.e("", "=======week days===========");
            }
            cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        }

    }

// only previous week days get
  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE dd-MMM-yyyy");
        for (int i = 7; i >=1; i--) {
            Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
            calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -i);
            String day = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
            System.out.println(day+"<<<" );
        }
```

Comment: Monday 20-Nov-2017
Tuesday 21-Nov-2017
Wednesday 22-Nov-2017
Thursday 23-Nov-2017
Friday 24-Nov-2017
Saturday 25-Nov-2017
Sunday 26-Nov-2017

Comment: i want current month of all weeks of current start date and end date

Comment: Thanks
But ony problem is i want previous weeks not next of current date
it will show
 Thursday 30-Nov-2017<<<

Comment: whole month get all days that y display Thursday 30-Nov-2017<<<

Comment: Last values are 
Wednesday 29-Nov-2017
Thursday 30-Nov-2017
I want data Wed to Wed  means
Wednesday 29-Nov-2017 to Wednesday 6-Dec-2017